# Understanding proof with isomorphic field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, quotient-spaces

I've read this proof:

[image]

Everything's clear except at the end where they said that if $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $I$ is the zero ideal.

How is that obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\alpha$ is transcendental if there is no polynomial in $K[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root. The kernel of $ev_\alpha$ by definition is then $\{0\}$ hence $I=(0)$.